# Java application profiling / tracking

Tags: java, profiling, trace

I have a closed source Java application for which vendor has provided APIs for customization. As I have no other documents, i rely completely on the API's javadoc.

I want to trace what methods are actually called in different classes for a particular use case. Is there any way to do that with eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Most profilers (like YourKit and JProfiler) support Eclipse integration.

Answer (score 1):

[JadClipse](http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a plug-in that allows you to decompile classes using [jad](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad), decompilation is available at the time of debugging.

There are some limitations, jad doesn't support java-5, and try catch functions don't always align nicely, but it can give you a good idea of whats going on inside.

See this thread too [is-jad-the-best-java-decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353/is-jad-the-best-java-decompiler)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use eclipse TPTP (http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/)

Personally I would use VisualVM or Netbeans profiler if possible

Answer (score 0):

[Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) has an [Eclipse plugin](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse), supporting Java 6, and works pretty well to decompile source and see what's inside the class files while debugging.